# Getting other tables Django filter/select_related

Tags: python, django

I am trying to filter values using Django's filter and select_related. I am able to get the base item, but I can't get any of the joined fields.

```
item = Items.objects.filter(tests__company_user_id__user_id=user_id).filter(item_id=item_id).select_related("tests__company_user").values()
```

My goal is to get data from the user associated with the item onto the item return. Is this possible?

The data model looks like this:

```
class Items(models.Model):
    item_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=100)
    mailed_date = models.DateTimeField()
    received_date = models.DateTimeField()
    last_viewed = models.DateTimeField()
    dateitemsent = models.DateTimeField()
    itemsent = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    itemret = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    dateitemret = models.DateTimeField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=25)

class Tests(models.Model):
    tests_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, unique=True, max_length=100)
    teststypetest_id = models.ForeignKey(TestsType)
    dateitemord = models.DateTimeField()
    testdate = models.DateTimeField()
    teststypetest_id = models.ForeignKey(TestsType)
    dateitemord = models.DateTimeField()
    testdate = models.DateTimeField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    item_id = models.ForeignKey(Kits)
    company_user_id = models.ForeignKey(CompanyUser)

class CompanyUser(models.Model):
    user_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=100)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=254,default="empty")
        sec_question_1 = models.CharField(max_length=254)
        sec_answer_1 = models.CharField(max_length=254)
        sec_question_2 = models.CharField(max_length=254)
        sec_answer_2 = models.CharField(max_length=254)
        sec_question_3 = models.CharField(max_length=254)
        sec_answer_3 = models.CharField(max_length=254)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use [select_related()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) you are caching joined object info but not retrieving, you need explicitly pull data:

```
item = Items.objects.filter(tests__company_user_id__user_id=user_id).filter(item_id=item_id).select_related("tests__company_user").values("tests__company_user_id__sec_question_1", "tests__company_user_id__sec_question_2", ...)
```

**EDIT**

Let's suppose you just want 2 fields from `CompanyUser`: `sec_question_1` and `sec_question_2`:

```
from django.db.models import F

item = Items.objects.filter(tests__company_user_id__user_id=user_id).filter(item_id=item_id).select_related("tests__company_user").values().annotate(q1=F('tests__company_user_id__sec_question_1'), q2=F('tests__company_user_id__sec_question_2'))
```

Comment: Shouldn't values retrieve the data?

Comment: `.values()` will retrieve data for `Item` object, because you are making a query to `Item` table.

Comment: How do I retrieve data for the Item object, as well as for the User object? Would I have to manually input each field in select_related(), for both models?

Comment: Nope, you could use annotate. I will update the answer.

Comment: Your update does not return any Item related data at all. I want the Item data and the User data.

Comment: Can you please run your query only with the first filter and tell what does it return?

Comment: With only the first filter, it gets all of the values from Items. If I want to use select_related, I have to manually indicate which variables I want to select. That seems to work, so I may do that.

Comment: That's and option as in my first answer, but annotate should do the work. I have tested this code and it works, check your relations and field names in query